# Doctrine: Can I flush only one class of entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I like the general idea of passing Doctrine repositories as services in Symfony2 and avoiding passing EntityManager. However, while it's fine when reading data, the saving logic becomes a bit problematic here.

Let's take this as a reference: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/, but with a change separating persisting and flushing:

```
class DoctrineORMCustomerRepository extends EntityRepository implements CustomerRepository
{
    public function persist(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->_em->persist($customer);
    }

    public function flush()
    {
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

The problem is you flush in a particular repository all changes in all entities.

Now, is it possible to flush just one class of entities? (possibly cascading to dependent entities), so I could basically do something like:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $this->customerRepository->persist($customer);
}

$this->customerRepository->flush();
```

I considered something like:

```
$this->_em->flush(getUnitOfWork()->getIdentityMap()[$this->_entityName]);
```

But I must have misunderstood something, because it doesn't work.

EDIT: Yes, I'm aware I can do `$this->_em->flush($entity)`, but doing this one by one is suboptimal. I even know I can do `$this->_em->flush($arrayOfEntities)`, but to make the "foreach" example work this way I'd have to keep track of all the persisted entities in the repository duplicating some Doctrine internals.

Comment: Nope.  In fact you hinted at the reason.  Entities tend to have relations with other entities.  If you really need this sort of isolation then use multiple entity managers.  But in practice, I never found flushing the entity manager to be a problem.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$em->flush($entity);
```

Then doctrine only will flush $entity, ignoring any other.

Comment: @MohammedZayan do note that passing object to `flush` method of `EntityManager` has been deprecated and is scheduled for removal in ORM 3.0.
See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#bc-break-removed-entitymanagerflushentity-and-entitymanagerflushentities

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: you must loop through all loaded entities, check it's class and flush the entity if has class you need.

See \ORM\EntityManager [flush() function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#354):

```
$this->unitOfWork->commit($entity);
```

[\ORM\UnitOfWork](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html) class has some functions you can use, start from [commit() function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#322)

Comment: yeah code $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->commit($entity) can be seen here https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.6/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L359

Answer (score 3):

You could try to pass the entity instance you want to persist to the flush method of the entity repository, as example:

```
    $this->_em->flush($entity);
```

According of the doc of the `Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager` class the method [flush](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L354):

```
 * If an entity is explicitly passed to this method only this entity and
 * the cascade-persist semantics + scheduled inserts/removals are synchronized.
 *
 * @param null|object|array $entity
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException If a version check on an entity that
 *         makes use of optimistic locking fails.
 * @throws ORMException
 */
public function flush($entity = null)
```

Hope this help

Comment: I don't want to flush entities one by one, I'd loose this way all possible optimizations Doctrine does. I'd rather flush all persisted entities of one class in a single flush.